# array search, not printing ket values more than once

Tags: php

I used foreach to print all keys and values. "$devicename_key" is printing the key which is fine but "$devicetype_key" is not printing. I see the value of 129 exist in array.

I have array with id in one row and value in next, its coming from database and I was able to clean it up in something like this. If there is another way to do this, please feel free to tell me.

I am getting the key for 128 adding 1 to it and then printing the value of 128. 129 is not printing.

```
Key=0, Value=:128
Key=1, Value=:TCM-7811
Key=2, Value=:129
Key=3, Value=:2
Key=4, Value=:130
Key=5, Value=:3

    foreach($extrafield_info as $x => $x_value) {
        echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
       echo "<br>";
    }
    // device name  128
    $deviceid_key = array_search('128', $extrafield_info);
    //echo 'device id key is ' . $deviceid_key;
    $devicename_key = $deviceid_key +1 ;
    //echo 'device key is ' . $devicename_key;

    // device type 129
    if (array_key_exists('129', $extrafield_info)) {
        $devicetype_key = array_search('129', $extrafield_info);
        echo 'key is ' . $devicetype_key;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `array_search(128, $extrafield_info)` (no single quotes on value)?

Comment: yes that doesn't work either. code for 128 works fine and same code for 129 doesnt print anything.

Comment: nope, lol that's how I had it first.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `array_key_exists` in your final `if` check, but 129 is not the key, it is the value.

Comment: tried that already.
even this doesn't print anything. 
-------------
$devicetype_key = array_search('129', $extrafield_info);
echo 'key is ' . $devicetype_key;
-------------------
This same exact code works fine for 128. It is so strange. I even cleared cache to see if it helps.

Comment: When I take your code and just change `if (array_key_exists('129', $extrafield_info))` to `if (array_search('129', $extrafield_info) !== false)` I get the expected "key is" echo at the end.

Comment: and how do I print the key? main thing I am trying to do is to print the key into a variable.

Comment: if (array_search('129', $extrafield_info) !== false) {
        $devicetype_key = array_search('129', $extrafield_info);
        echo 'key is ' . $devicetype_key;
    }

changed the code, this didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do:

```
$extrafield_info[]  = 128;
$extrafield_info[]  = 'TCM-7811';
$extrafield_info[]  = 129;
$extrafield_info[]  = 2;
$extrafield_info[]  = 130;
$extrafield_info[]  = 3;

// Fetch key value for 128 (ends up being 0)
$deviceid_key = array_search(128, $extrafield_info);

// Get next key (should be now 1)
$devicename_key = ($deviceid_key +1) ;

// Insert next key for search for new $devicename_key (1)
if(array_key_exists($devicename_key, $extrafield_info)) {
    // Should return key 2
    $devicetype_key = array_search(129, $extrafield_info);
    echo 'key is ' . $devicetype_key;
}
```

Comment: ideal situation but gives me blank like before. I wonder if any one experience the same problem with this before. Below code gives me 2.
if ($extrafield_info[2] = 129 )
{
 echo 'device type' . $extrafield_info[3];
}

Comment: Then I am confused. Echoing  `$extrafield_info[3]` should give you `2` because the value of `key 3` is `2`. What are you hoping to get? Like what number should be returned there?

Comment: I figured it out. I have ":" in my values and it is throwing off everything.
I just fixed this.